# Construct an object from multiple sources including a vector of objects

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, factory, lookup

I get different fields [of potentially one class] from two different sources on the fly in c++. 
First a class A's fields gets passed on in function #1 (getData_Main) and then a vector of fields in another local function #2(getVecor_Sublass);
The function calls are always sequential #1 followed by #2.
Here are the simplified data structures;

```
class Subclass {
    string str;
    string str2;
    //a few other fields 
};

class Main {
    string name;
    float somevar;
    // few more string fields
    vector<Subclass> vecSubclass; 
};
```

I need to save the state of data to make it persistent to be used in other interfaces, something like construct a `vector<Main*>` object vector.
I thought about creating a variable that serves as an index to main class and use the same index in Subclass and form a sort of lookup table? But then how to do that in best possible and more efficient way?

Unfortunately I'm not much familiar with the modern C++ (11/14) features and constructs, still a c++ 03 developer) so thought about posting here to get some suggestions with some working piece of code snippet in case of lambdas or any newer features?

```
class Main 
{
    int index; //create from some static variable in function A and pass on to function B 
    string name;
    float somevar;
    vector<A> vecA;
};
```

**Update (Answering the comments)**

Input is the **data fields** coming from java/jni native functions;

Desired output is the *`vector<Main>`* objects.

Issue#1 is the input fields of one java class are coming in two native functions, so C++ is getting two sets of fields (Set#1 is all the fields of **Main** class and set#2 is  **`vector<Subclass>`** contained in class `Main` fields;).

*I'm just trying to reconstruct the object and trying different options.*

As they are coming in local functions, there is nothing common to rebuild the **vector** objects unless we do something like creating an index to serve as a key and build vector objects in C++ from these two sources.
Issue#2 is how to do it in best possible way.

I hope the question makes some sense now?

Edited to add the following Java code which we are trying to mimic the functionality of:

```
public class MainLine {
    String name;
    String Locator;
    Sub[] SubList = new Sub[5];
}
public class Test {
   MainLine[] MainLineArray = new MainLine[10000];
    // Data coming from some other sources in Java
   for (int j=0;j<10000;j++){
       test.addMainLine(MainLineArray[j].Locator, MainLineArray[j].name);
       for (int k=0;k<5;k++) {
        test.addSubList(MainLineArray[j].SubList[k].field1, MainLineArray[j].SubList[k].field2, MainLineArray[j].subList[k].field3,.....);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't catch what is desired. A lot of "some" used. Could you elaborate function calls, how it is expected to be used.

Comment: It sounds like you want to pass an object of class `A` into a function? I'm having trouble understanding your use case. What are you building? What's the blackbox? What is its input and output?

Comment: Let me update the question.

Comment: I don't understand from the question why the same index would be used to index into a vector of Main and a vector of SubClass?  Unless you mean that when you have an object of Subclass then you need to be able to find the Main class that owns it.  In which case why not just put a Main* pointer into Subclass?

Comment: Jerry as i couldn't think of any other way to build a vector<Main> which 'contains' a vector<Subclass> , that is where i got confused that like how else to construct that? If the inputs are coming from two different sources? think this way input is a Main class from java but it is sending half fields in one function, half in another.

Comment: You're trying to reconstruct some functionality from Java? Could you post the Java code that achieves your functionality?

Comment: I think you are focusing too much on how you want to do something, and using far too little text explaining what that something is. In addition to being unclear, you run the risk of delving into an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I was hoping the Java code would help me understand but unfortunately I don't. I think there may be an insurmountable language barrier. If you were to describe the functionality of this program from scratch (as if no Java version of it existed), how would you describe it?

Comment: John, that is why i tried to not mention Java in my original question; Anyhow, I would describe "How to efficiently construct a vector of objects (that include one member variable as another vector of subclass objects) from two sources (two local functions)".  It is basically reconstructing vector<MainLine> in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to make an object whose fields are made of data got in multiple separate calls of certain functions. In general to deal with these type situations you need to pass identifiers or something to the object-building functions to find out which values belong to which object.

But in JNI case as yours, a native function can return an address as `jlong` pointing to an incomplete object under construction to the Java program, which in turn can be repeatedly passed to native functions updating the same object.

In Java:

```java
native static long createMain(int val);

native static void addSubToMain(long main, int val);

void createMainsInNative() {
  long main = createMain("a");
  addSubToMain(main, "X");
  addSubToMain(main, "Y");
}
```

In C++:

```cpp
class Main {
  int val;
  std::vector<Sub> subs;
};

class Sub { int val; };

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Main>> g_mains;

JNIEXPORT jlong Java_SomeClass_createMain(JEnv*, jclass, jint val)
{
  auto obj = std::make_unique<Main>();
  auto raw = static_cast<jlong>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(obj.get()));
  obj->val = val;
  g_mains.emplace_back(std::move(obj));
  return raw
}

JNIEXPORT void Java_SomeClass_addSubToMain(JEnv*, jclass, jlong main, jint val)
{
  reinterpret_cast<Main*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(main))->subs.push_back(Sub { val });
}
```